# TouchPad doesn't work on Ubuntu 11.10, Toshiba Salellite L500-1WP

Tags: 11.10, mouse, touchpad, pointers

TouchPad stopped working about two weeks ago. Everything else is working. On Windows 7 it's working. I think, problem is in OS. What can I do?
Excuse my English, I don't know it. :-(

Answer (score 1):

First update all your packages.

Than

- sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
- dconf-editor
- Search for: /org/gnome/settings-daemon/peripherals/touchpad/
- Check "touchpad-enabled"

Answer (score 1):

Try doing the following

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
```

then

```
sudo modprobe psmouse
```